# mysql - for each row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have written an insert trigger. woo.

The next step is that I want to run a query or procedure after the trigger has run. So not for each record inserted but after the inserts.

Where do I put this call?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER /*!50033 IF EXISTS */ triggername $$


CREATE TRIGGER triggername
AFTER INSERT ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

/*This runs for each insert - I want it to run at the end of the trigger*/
CALL UpdateOtherStuff(NEW.fieldA, NEW.fieldB);

END$$
```

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: Does it have to run after all inserts have finished, or would only once after the first insert suffice?  Actually, more to the point, to what would the procedure arguments `NEW.fieldA` and `NEW.fieldB` refer in the event that you're not referring to a single inserted record?

Comment: Yes after all the inserts have finished. I would drop the parameters from the procedure and rewrite it if it was rung after all the inserts.

Comment: If a multi-insert statement inserts 10 rows, you want to call the procedure after the 10 rows have been inserted. However, if the application elects to insert those 10 rows via separate `INSERT` statements, you would still call the procedure 10 separate times.  Should an application's implementation detail really effect database behaviour in this way? Wouldn't it be better either to call the procedure after every row (as you currently do), or else call the procedure periodically via the event scheduler and do no work if none is required (e.g. you could track the rows that have been processed)?

Comment: All true enough. I just wondered if it was possible. I think the event scheduler will solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL trigger syntax is limited. You can't have multiple triggers on the same table. You can't have database level triggers.

In short you can't do that because MySQL doesn't know if you're inserting 1000 values or just one. They are each separate events even if you're triggering them from one single statement.

`FOR EACH ROW` is a fixed part of the `CREATE TRIGGER` syntax and it's not optional.

When I've had the same problem I implemented stored functions and used the functions to do both the inserting and the update code.

The limits of functions and stored procedures are many such as not being able to pass a variable number of parameters to them (like you can pass to insert / update) or not being able to pass WHERE clauses to them so that they can filter what they are affecting.

But you can overcome the filtering limitation like such:

```
CREATE FUNCTION x(id INTEGER) ...

SELECT x(object_id) FROM objects WHERE ...
```

I'm not sure if MySQL will optimise this as in execute the function right on the spot and having the object data it doesn't need to reselect it within the function. But i think it doesn't... it think the update query inside the function runs as per usual.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am unaware of the limits of triggers.